# Problema com função pow()

Tags: c, compilação, biblioteca

Alguém saberia me dizer por que o seguinte código não compila?

```
#include <math.h>

double f(double x){
      return (x - (pow(2,x)));
}
```

Comment: Qual o erro apresentado?

Comment: referência indefinida para `pow'

Comment: Como está a correr o código ? Como foi compilado ? Se foi através de um IDE qual foi ? Se foi compilado à mão inclua o comando que utilizou

Comment: Isso é erro de linkagem, imagino, devido à mensagem. Não é de compilação. Tente compilar com a opção `-c` se estiver usando o GCC (creio que ICC também siga as mesmas flags)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compilar, compila. Mas não *linka* porque a biblioteca matemática não foi adiciona ao processo de *build*  do executável.

A biblioteca referenciada pelo cabeçalho `math.h` não é *linkada* por padrão como outras básicas, até porque ela pode mudar de acordo com a plataforma, e você tem que dizer que deseja que ela seja usada no processo de *build*, então coloque isto na linha de comando do compilador:

```
-lm
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Funcionou, era isso mesmo, obrigado