# Sobre a inclusão de headers (.h) e a devida compilação

Tags: c, compilação, header, include, gcc

Supondo que eu crie um arquivo `.h` para a especificação de uma função

#### func.h

```
#ifndef FUNC_H
#define FUNC_H

int xPy(int x, int y);

#endif //FUNC_H
```

e depois criei a implementação dessa função em um arquivo `.c`, como:

#### func.c

```
int xPy(int x, int y) {
   int result;
   result = x+y;
   return result;
}
```

Eu poderei incluir o `"func.h"` em um novo arquivo (suponhamos `main.c`)

Suposto código de `main.c`

```
#include "func.h"

int main() {
   int a = func(10, 10);
   return 0;
}
```

Até aí tudo bem, porém, no processo de compilação parece não ser o bastante fazer

```
gcc main.c -o main
```

Eu tenho de fazer

```
gcc func.c main.c -o main
```

Eu gostaria de saber o porquê disto ser necessário. A diretiva `#include "func.h"` não deveria fazer o compilador buscar o arquivo `func.c` automaticamente?

No caso estou usando GCC 8.2.0.

Comment: @maniero 

Eu imaginei que o compilador fosse buscar o arquivo .c pelo fato de quando eu faço um `#include <stdio.h>` por exemplo, o arquivo stdio.h possui apenas a assinatura da função `printf`, a implementação dessa função fica em outro arquivo e o compilador adicional de forma transparente.

Comment: Imagino que queria comentar na resposta, mas vamos lá. Aí está falando de biblioteca que de fato o compilador coloca automaticamente porque ele sabe tudo o que precisava saber sobre isso e é mais pra´tico na maioria dos casos, mas note que isso nem é verdade em todas bibliotecas, a `math` não é automática: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/286771/101

Comment: nunca havia utilizado o site para fazer perguntas antes, mas obrigado pelos esclarecimentos, me ajudou muito

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se reler sua pergunta, analisando o texto com cuidado, já terá a resposta. Nele está escrito que você quer que o `func.c` seja incluído na sua aplicação. Você diz que já usou o `#include "func.h"`. Onde você está incluindo o `func.c`? Na linha de comando do compilador. Ora, se não colocar em algum lugar, e este é o lugar, como o compilador saberá que é para colocá-lo. Portanto a resposta objetiva e direta para sua pergunta é que precisa ser colocado em algum lugar, não tem como o compilador adivinhar.

Em seguida especula sobre ele fazer automático. Mas que automação seria esta? Como colocar o `func.h` faria o compilador adivinhar que deveria colocar alguma outra coisa? Que coisa seria esta? Será que está pensando que porque colocou um arquivo chamado `func` com extensão `.h` deveria colocar também um outro com extensão `.c`?

Isso não faz sentido, porque estes nomes, essas extensões são meras convenções. Na verdade faria bem pouco sentido porque um arquivo `.c` pode precisar de mais de um `.h` ou o contrário e um `.h` se referir a implementações que estão em mais de um `.c`. E mais, o `.h` nem é obrigatório. E nem estou falando da extensão que poderia ser outra, o cabeçalho não é obrigatório (ainda que possa gerar algumas dificuldades futuras de organização, mas é só algo que você escolhe para seu projeto).

Uma coisa nada tem a ver com outra. Inclusive a inclusão é só uma maneira de trazer um texto que está em outro arquivo para o arquivo atual, nada mais que isso, a diretiva sequer processa seu conteúdo, não tem inteligência, é só parte de um pré-processador, nem é o compilador em si que está operando ali.

Pode ler mais em:

- [Quando se inclui um arquivo de cabeçalho, o compilador inclui todas as funções no programa final ou só as funções usadas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57701/101)
- [O que são os arquivos com extensão .cpp e .h?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/240579/101)
- [Como importar funções de outro arquivo em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154070/101)
- [Como criar um aquivo.h?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76782/101)
- [Como funciona a diretiva "#include"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45021/101)